# Циклы for в java

Tags: java, циклы, if, for

У меня появилась одна идея и чтобы ее реализовать мне нужна ваша помощь.
Можно ли в цикле, for, while, do while, не имеет значения, написать код, который будет выполнен только один раз, то есть:

```
boolean variable = false;
for (int i;i==10;i++) {
    System.out.println("OK");
    if (i==5) {
        variable = true;
    }

    if (variable==true) {
        System.out.println(variable);
    }

}
```

Как сделать чтобы if выполнился только 1 раз, и не выполнялся больше в цикле, чтобы получить наибольшую оптимизацию.

Comment: добавить break; последней строкой в if

Comment: Если код должен выполняться один раз, то стоит вынести его из цикла

Answer (score 1):

```
if (variable==true){
System.out.println(variable);
break;
}
```

Comment: А после brake; я могу писать команды которые будут повторяться? :-)

Comment: Вы выйдите из цикла после break;

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно никаких дополнительных переменных.

```
if (i==5) {
    // здесь код
    }
```

Будет выполнено в цикле один раз - кода `i` равно 5.

Comment: Спасибо, я так и сделал